# why angularjs core need to detect whether module ngLocale has been created?

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJS source code, there is a section like this, the comment is added by me

```
try {
    angularModule('ngLocale'); //this detect wether ngLocale has been created
} catch (e) {
    //if not created , then create it here
    angularModule('ngLocale', []).provider('$locale', $LocaleProvider);    
}
```

I understand how `ngLocale` works, because you can override default `ngLocale`'s `$locale` service by using files like

```
<script src="../src/ngLocale/angular-locale_fr-ca.js"></script>
```

But this after AngularJS core has been run. Because the exception always throw, literally, why not just remove the detection code, and simply use that instead?

```
angularModule('ngLocale', []).provider('$locale', $LocaleProvider);
```

Comment: It is certainly irritating that this exception is thrown every time the page is loaded.

Comment: use firefox to debug this - this is an error with angular+chrome-- http://www.congral.com/2014/05/29/have-you-already-encountered-the-uncaught-object-exception/

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is because angularjs lacks the ability to check for the availability of a module on a graceful manner. So instead of a checkModule() or findModule(), the framework needs to induce a "module loading exception" for the nonexistent module.

ensure module could accept a parameter to tell the system if it is OK to not find a module, and simply return null as a result.

Actually, letting the module name to start with a question mark  in the var mod = angular.module("?moduleName") code path (and not when defining a  module) would make it a simple oneliner code to ommit exceptions.

Comment: please add one snippet